# Which is better encodeing for activation hash, sha1 or base64_encode

Tags: php, base64, sha1

I am currently building a basic auth syste, and i have an user activation feature what generates a 20 character long string and encodes it to `sha1` , but i saw a few other systems use `base64_encode` could please someone explain what is better and why?

Thank you

Comment: what data is in the "20 character long string"? If it is just a random string of characters, there would be no difference other than length and no real difference/security in just using the 20 character string.

Comment: Please see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/549/1741542

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could scrap the idea of even encoding/hashing the string and use [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/openssl-random-pseudo-bytes) to generate a string and then use that.

```
echo bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10));
```

Example output:

```
root@upstairslinux:/var/www# php openssl.php
67b206be9ceef1c4974f

root@upstairslinux:/var/www#
```

Comment: you just gave me a good idea with this and confirmed something what i was not sure about, thanks

Answer (score 2):

they are quite different -- `SHA1` is a one way hash function, which means that you cannot go back from the encoded string to the original string. However, `base64_encode` is a two way encoding function, meaning you can get the original value back using `base64_decode`.

Security wise, it means that anyone who gets his hands on a `base64_encode`d value can easily decode it, whereas a `SHA1` value required brute force, and a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You are generating a string of random characters. No kind of encoding or hashing is likely to bring you any benefits.

`sha1` will make the string shorter and make it (very very slightly) easier to guess the required string.

`base64` will make the string longer and make it more likely that wordwrapping will break any URL you inject it into.

Comment: sha1 is 40 characters, not shorter than 20. And base64 has on average a 33% increase in size over the original string.